# RavenDB - When I do want a reference to another Root Aggregate

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have been using DDD for a while know so I am comfortable with the idea of aggregates.  At first I did have troubles wrapping my head around not using/persisting references to other root aggregates but I think I'm on board... so:

- Storing a root aggregate as a one document.... check
- Using denormalized references containing properties that do not change or rarely change.... check

For the times that I DO want to have a full reference to another root aggregate, I understand it is recommended that I persist a reference to its ID and can use the RavenDB client API's *Includes* to retrieve all the entities efficiently.

That handles the data part, what I haven't seen is the best way to handle this in my entity class:

1. Have both *Product* and *ProductId* properties in my class using **[JsonIgnore]** on the *Product* to ensure it doesn't get persisted with the document.

   - The full object graph could then be glued back together in the repository (using API's *Includes* for efficiency) or I could inject a service into the entity that would fetch *Product* lazily (possible N+1 hit)
2. Glue it back together in a ViewModel.  I don't like this idea as I could end up with an unexpected NULL reference in the domain if not used correctly.
3. Some other obvious way that I'm not seeing?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DDD there are at least two valid points of view. Some ppl link root aggregates only by ID or another valid key and second is using platform specific references to other objects. Both has it's own pros and cons.

With NoSql solutions like RavenDb, it's probably better to use first approach, because second is just technically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are going explicitly against the recommended design here, why *do* you want a Product property refering to another aggregate? What does it gives you?

Comment: Using Product was a bad example as you have used this in many examples of when to denormalize. In RavenDB Mythology Documentation (I realize it is still draft), an example is provided of Customer's 'LastLogin' (2.1.4 - What to denormalize).  "If you really need the full associated document, you need to explicitly load it".  I agree it is hard to think of times when this is actually required.  As you can see in my question, I was asking for advice on what is a good way to do this (explicitly load it) when I DO believe I need to (as a fringe case).